# Firebase DeltaSnapshot incorrect Key returned (node.js server)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

With Google Cloud Functions for Firebase using Node.js, I'm trying to get the keys of the current deltasnapshot within two nested foreach loops.

1st level key is correct 'incoming'

2nd level is invalid 'incomingABCDEFGHI'   // ABCDEFGHI being a unique id for accounts

3rd level key correct '-ewroiu5o345o534535' // Firebase Push ID

console.log(snapshot.key);

```
    snapshot.forEach(function(accountSnapshot){


        accountSnapshot.forEach(function(orderSnapshot){


          console.log(snapshot.key);
          console.log(accountSnapshot.key);
          console.log(orderSnapshot.key);


        });

    });
```

For some reason the 2nd level key returns both 1st level and 2nd level key combined (without a slash or space)

The DeltaSnapshot is triggered by a Database 'onWrite'

Anyone had anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. If my path were to be '1/2/3', the key would output 23 as opposed to 3. They have a method that outputs the full path of a child, and they seem to omit that slash. Add this to the top of your index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

functions.database.DeltaSnapshot.prototype._fullPath = function () {
    var out = (this._path || '') + '/' +(this._childPath || '');
    if (out === '') {
        out = '/';
    }
    return out;
}
```

I submitted an issue on GitHub, and it can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/36).

Comment: Yeh I did implement this type of solution in my code, but in the end I just rejigged my db structure and calls.

Least i'm not the only one that had this.